# Dummycoding based on clustering from OM distances

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, traminer

I'm using TraMineR to determine a certain clustering based on Optimal Matching distances:

```
# Define a sequence object
sequences.seq <- seqdef(sequences, left="DEL", right="DEL", gaps="DEL", missing="")

# Compute OM costs
costs <- seqsubm(sequences.seq, method="TRATE")

# Create OM object
sequences.om <- seqdist(sequences.seq, method="OM", indel=1, sm=costs, with.missing=FALSE, norm="maxdist")

# Use OM object to create a dendrogram
clusterward <- agnes(sequences.om, diss = TRUE, method = "ward")
plot(clusterward, labels=colnames(sequences))
```

This gives me a plot of a dendrogram. Now I want to dummycode the cases in my dataset dependent on which cluster they fall in. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first retrieve the cluster membership vector. For this, you need to specify the number of groups (The WeightedCluster library provides cluster quality measures that may help you to choose a good number of cluster: see http://mephisto.unige.ch/weightedcluster)

```
numgroup <- 5
clustmember <- cutree(clusterward, k=numgroup)
## Visualize your clustering
seqdplot(sequences.seq, group=clustmember, with.missing=TRUE)
## Now transform it into a dummy matrix
clusterdummy <- matrix(0, nrow=length(clustmember), ncol=numgroup)
for(i in 1:numgroup){
    clusterdummy[, i] <- as.integer(clustmember==i)
}
```

Now the matrix clusterdummy contains your dummies.

Comment: An alternative perhaps more efficient way of creating the dummies is with the `dummy` function from the `dummies` library: `clusterdummy <- dummy(clustmember)`.